# Make voice calls from D-ink hspa datacard proprietary modem

Tags: java, telephony

I am using 'D-ink hspa datacard proprietary modem' and the application provided along with it allows to send sms but does not allow voice calls. My question is whether it is possible to make a java application which can connect to the modem and make voice calls via a phone dialer.